# Python how to get labels of a generated adjacency matrix from networkx graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, adjacency-matrix

If i've an networkx graph from a python dataframe and i've generated the adjacency matrix from it. 
So basically, how to get labels of that adjacency matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you refer to nodes' labels, networkx only keeps the the indices when extracting a graph's adjacency matrix. Networkx represents each node as an index, and you can add more attributes if you wish. All node's attributes except for the index are kept in a dictionary. When generating graph's adjacency matrix only the indices are kept, so **if you only wish to keep a single string per node, consider indexing nodes by that string when generating your graph**.

Answer (score -1):

If the adjacency matrix is generated without passing the nodeList, then you can call G.nodes to obtain the default NodeList, which should correspond to the rows of the adjacency matrix.